# Display image from apex_application_temp_files in interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How in interactive report display thumb of image?

```
select ID,FILENAME,MIME_TYPE,
decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("BLOB_CONTENT"),0),0,NULL,
       '<img src = "' ||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('',ID)||'"width = "100"/>') "PICTURE"
from
apex_application_temp_files
```

Answer (score 0):

As first parameter in get_blob_file_src function you have to provide a valid application page ITEM that with type FILE that contains the source type of DB column.

read more about get_blob_file_src [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_util.htm#AEAPI129)